# How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+x^\alpha)} \mathbb dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I see somewhere that the value of the integral
$$
I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+x^\alpha)} \mathbb dx,\alpha\in \mathbb R^+
$$
does not depend on $\alpha$. So $I=\pi/4$ for all $\alpha$. How can I prove this?

I tackled the special case $\alpha=2$ quite easily by contour integration, but find it quite awkward to deal with general $\alpha$. Contour integration doesn't seem to work for $\alpha=\sqrt 2$, for example.

I tried $dI/d\alpha$ and $I(\alpha)-I(\beta)$, but both lead to very complicated functions that don't lead to anywhere.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Right. Fixed. There is a discontinuity at 0.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1465329/42969.