# Improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^n)(1+x²)}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to find the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^n)(1+x²)}.$$

I enter small values of $n$ on Wolfram and it seems like the answer should be $\pi /4$. Can anyone confirm this for any $n$? I try to do fraction decomposition but it gets ugly really fast.

(I think this should have been answered somewhere but I really can’t find it. Apologize in advance if this is a duplication)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form of integral using contour integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465329/closed-form-of-integral-using-contour-integration) See also: [is the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}$ equal for all $a \neq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87735/is-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-mathrmd-x1x21xa-equal-for-al).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**trick** : Make substituition $x=\frac{1}{t}$

ie integral becomes $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^ndt}{(1+t^2)(1+t^n)}$$.

Adding this with original integral:

$$2I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+t^n}{(1+t^2)(1+t^n)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^n)(1+x^2)}~~~~(*)$$
Let $x=\tan t$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{1+\tan^nt}~~~~~~~(1)$$
Use the property: $\int_{0}^a f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx~~~~(2)$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{1+\cot^n t}~~~~(3)$$
Add (1) and (3), to get
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^n t}+\frac{1}{1+\cot^n t}\right)dt=\frac{\pi}{2} \implies I=\frac{\pi}{4}$$